# Getting unexpected output from my program

Tags: java, methods, jgrasp

I am currently in the process of making a Tractor rental program and so far I have a main method that tests the tractor and a Tractor class. First I will post the tractor class than I will post the main method:

Tractor class :

```
class Tractor
{
   private int RentalRate;
   private int RentalDays;
   private int VehicleID;
   private int RentalProfit;

    public void setRentalRate(int r)
    {
      if (r > 0) {
            this.RentalDays = r;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: bad RentalRate!");
        }
         RentalDays = r;  
    } 

    public int getRentalRate() 
    {
      return this.RentalRate;
    }  

   public void setVehicleID(int v)
    {
      if (v > 0) {
            this.VehicleID = v;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: bad VehicleID!");
        }
         RentalDays = v;      
    }

    public int getVehicleID()
    {
      return this.VehicleID;  
    }

    public void setRentalDays(int d)
    {
      if (d > 0) {
            this.RentalDays = d;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: bad Rental Days!");
       }
         RentalDays = d;    
   }

    public int getRentalDays()
    {
      return this.RentalDays;
   }

    public int RentalProfit(int RentalRate, int RentalDays)  
    {
      RentalProfit = RentalRate * RentalDays;
      return this.RentalProfit;
    }   

    //Tractor(int RD, int RR, int RP, int VID)
    //{
      //RentalDays = RD;
      //RentalRate = RR;
      //RentalProfit = RP;
      //VehicleID = VID;

    //}


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  "Tractor (Rental days = " + RentalDays + ", Rental Rate = " + RentalRate + 
        ", Rental profit = " +  RentalProfit + ", VehicleID = " + VehicleID + ")";
    }
```

Main Method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
          Tractor tractor;
          tractor = new Tractor();
          tractor.setRentalRate(9);
          tractor.setRentalDays(45);
          tractor.setVehicleID(9145949);
          System.out.println(tractor.toString());
```

See below the output the program is giving me, I've looked through my code multiple times and can't figure out why this is.

```
Tractor (RentalDays = 9145949, Rental Rate = 0, Rental profit = 0, VehicleID 9145949)
```

Comment: There's something wrong with the design of that `RentalProfit` method: It calculates the values based on field values that not necessarily match the fields of the class (but you could use the field values and remove the method parameters). Also you calculate and store the value here and never use it except in the toString method which is bad for various reasons: This method is something like a getter method, but other toString relies on that method being called (which is not necessarily the case); the value in the field may therefore not be up to date.

Comment: scratch that I figured it out thanks for the help, i had to set it as a set and get method than add tractor.setRentalProfit(); in my main method

Comment: The thing is there should not be a set method and not a field. Replace all uses of the field with the use of the getter(which recalculates the value every time based on the values of the other fields). That way the value is always up to date. The alternative would be keeping the field and adding a `recalculateRentalProfit` method and call it every time a value the rental profit depends on gets set (in the setters).

Answer (score 1):

Your `setRentalRate` method is incorrect. In this method you set the 'RentalDays' instead of the 'RentalRate'.

```
public void setRentalRate(int r)
{
    if (r > 0) {
        this.RentalDays = r; // Should be this.RentalRate = r;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error: bad RentalRate!");
    }
    RentalDays = r; // Should be RentalRate = r;
}
```

Also, I'm confused as to why you set it an additional time after the if-else. I think it should be something like this:

```
public void setRentalRate(int r)
{
    if (r > 0) {
        this.RentalRate = r;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error: bad RentalRate!");
        RentalRate = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the "weird output" you mentioned is that the rental days equals the vehicle ID? If so, see below.

```
public void setVehicleID(int v)
{
  if (v > 0) {
        this.VehicleID = v;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error: bad VehicleID!");
    }
     *****RentalDays = v;*****  <-- This is why.    
}
```

Comment: Wow, you people are quick!